# How long would a copy of Windows 10 be supported?

Tags: windows-10, license

If I purchase a Windows home license, how long would it be supported for?

I remember, Microsoft announced, that there will be no more Windows 11 after Windows 10 and that Windows will just receive rolling updates again and again. But at the same time their website says that Windows 10 end of mainstream support (Bug fixes, features etc) is October 13, 2020. How these two correlate?

It seems surprising that you will get a perpetual Windows 10 license with all future updates ever coming out, right?

It's more clear with Microsoft Office, which [just has a rental cost](https://products.office.com/en-gb/office-365-home).

Does Microsoft have any official, canonical documents on this?

Comment: @journeyman Geek There is a factual based answer to this question (Hence why Vladislav asked for official doccumentation) The answer is here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet I was about to post about the life cycle and the windows 10 modular setup (allowing windows 10 to be essentially converted into a new operating system over time, which is an official document microsoft released)

Comment: @Tetsujin That's... not true. The retail licence can be transferred, just as in previous versions.

Comment: Well, it was that or a learning material recommendation. And I don't get how the retail cost of windows relates to "what you get", or the support period.

Comment: You get Windows 10 Home. No more, no less. Which, under the current model, receives all updates under that same name. If Microsoft decides to release Windows 9000 next year, they can do so - and you would still be entitled to updates to Windows 10 for as long as its support lifecycle lasts (no shorter than previous versions, extensions excluded).

Comment: The question is aggressively worded I believe, however it sounds like a question of "If I pay 120$ how long until Microsoft replace it with windows 11 and what updates do I receive while 10 is alive?" The fact is you get feature updates until 2020, and security updates until 2025 subject to Microsoft's willingness and ability to provide them.

Comment: @Lister You put it better than I did :) That's the support/update/lifecycle guarantee, which can be (but does not have to be) extended at Microsoft's discretion.

Comment: Yeah, the agressive wording is an issue. That said, would the OP be ok with editing it to be more factual?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Answer on standby if he is willing, I looked at rewording it, however it would be a lot like putting words into another persons mouth with the changes needed

Comment: Edited it to work better. OP's free to rollback or adjust the wording. I'll be clearing out the comments in a bit, but feel free to answer

Comment: Thank you all, guys, for comments, suggestions and corrections. What I want to know is how "There will be no Windows 11" statement by Microsoft correlates with the fact, that Windows 10 has the end of mainstream support declared for 2020. For me these two contradict a little.

Comment: @Vladislav End of support means there will be no updates to the system. Support could be limited to the most recent update only, i.e. Windows 10 with a specific update / build number. It could be called Windows 10 yet it would be another Windows 10 that you use now. And who knows, maybe there will be another version of Windows in future too. Additionally, Windows XP is out of support but people still use, you can still install a fresh copy of it. However, it's not recommended, of course.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Exactly. I just want to know what happens if I purchase a retail Windows 10 now, use only latest updates of it ever, transfer it to new hardware over next years to accomodate with new requirements if they come out. There will be no Windows 11 they say. Does that mean I can use Windows 10 forever in these conditions?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny - The terms of the license, with regard to how long you can use it, are identical for Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, and 10.  There are people using Windows 2000 today.  The only difference is that a Windows 10 feature update, might eventually be released that might not support your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

> their website says that Windows 10 end of mainstream support (Bug fixes, features etc) is October 13, 2020.

Wrong. There are two different support schemes in place.

### For LTSB version

[According to Microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=Windows%2010&Filter=FilterNO), each new LTSB version of Windows 10 has a new support date. For example, while the mainstream support end date of Windows Enterprise LSTB 2015 is indeed 13 October 2020, the mainstream support end date of Windows 10 Enterprise LSTB 2016 is 21 October 2021. So, don't worry: As Microsoft releases new versions of Windows 10, it sets newer support end dates at the expense of requiring people to upgrade to the latest major build.

### Non-LTSB versions

[According to Terry Myerson](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-commits-to-10-year-support-lifecycle-for-windows-10/), a Windows 10 device is supported throughout the life of the device. All a device needs to do to remain supported is to install new updates. So, no more stupid support end dates. If you install the latest update, you are supported. If not, you are not supported.

If you are expecting me to tell you what's the catch here, please re-read my last sentence and know that you probably won't be able to continue installing latest Microsoft updates on a given device forever. To quote:

> A device may not be able to receive updates if the device hardware is incompatible, lacking current drivers, or otherwise outside of the Original Equipment Manufacturer's ("OEM") support period.

Comment: I wonder then if for DIY systems the grandfather's axe model would work It wouldn't be too hard to replace *parts* of a system over say, 20 years

Comment: Well, what if I upgrade a device again and again and transfer Windows 10 license to it again and again? I mean the case with a boxed product, not OEM one. Can I use Windows 10 forever having paid $120 once in this case?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny Microsoft says "yes". But I can see the catch there, can't? You eventually have to buy a new device.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Changing the motherboard eventually voids the license, doesn't it? Linking your license to the Microsoft account gives you a couple of free shot but it won't last for ever.

Comment: @FleetCommand Only on OEM licences, retail can swap as much as they like.

Comment: @Lister A reference would be great.

Comment: @FleetCommand Reference from MVP: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/reusing-windows-10-retail-product-key-from-broken/2fc864db-a599-47ef-8e70-af1679a0f004 Also found the explicit licence term: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm Under point 4B standalone software

Comment: @Lister I meant a reference for "retail can swap as much as they like". Your reference explains the procedure but does not say it can be done repeatedly. Someone here in Superuser once mentioned a hard limit. Only if I could remember the topic...

Comment: @FleetCommand That I don't know, I can only say as far as the agreement goes its not limited. I imagine if you activate multiple devices and they call home, it would flag the key.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 end of mainstream support (Bug fixes, features etc) is October 13, 2020.

The end of extended support is October 14, 2025. Extended support tends to be only security updates.

More information on end of life [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet)

Microsoft have announced they have changed the way they are deploying updates. They plan on releasing feature updates 2-3 times a year.
Updates will be deployed monthly in one big cumulative update, rather than the smaller distributed patches than before.

More information on windows as a service [here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/waas-overview)

We can expect with Microsoft competing against Apple and Linux, and gearing more towards the Mac way of updating, that they will want to compete in feature sets.
Making the change to the update cycle allows them to push these updates out quicker.

Feature improvement examples included since release include:

- Bash Shell (Linux shell on windows)
- Virtual desktop pins (pin 1 window to all virtual desktops)
- An "Ink workspace" (dedicated area for stylus compatible apps"
- Customization notification settings (Set priorities for apps)
- Battery improvements (Apps not in use but are battery intensive will be slept)

Comment: I would like to understand how "there will be no Windows 11" statement correlates with "end of support" for Windows 10. Can you please clarify? I doubt Microsoft is going to shutdown, right?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny Think of it like the mac OS. Apple improve upon the operating system, rather than creating a new one. Microsoft may do the same. In essence it would be windows 10 still, but it would slowly change over time. They have made windows 10 modular, allowing them to change chunks at a time. All that is guaranteed at the moment is that your copy of Windows 10 will be supported until 2025. That is a lot of time for microsoft to change their mind!

Comment: I can't think about Windows like about MacOS because there is a boxed version of Windows I can purchase and use with any hardware. I can also upgrade/change hardware and transfer Windows license to it (if it's not an OEM one), right? Infinite hardware upgrade over years and infinite transfers of retail Windows 10 to it means perpetual Windows license forever, right?

Comment: Retail copies of windows can be transferred to new machines yes. Even in 2025 if windows 10 did die, you would still be able to move that licence to new machines and carry on using windows 10, just like people still use XP/Vista/7. There is one thing to consider, there are new processors coming out which Microsoft have not provided support for older operating systems on. For example only windows 10 can run on the new Kaby lake processors. This may happen to windows 10 in its old age, depending on what Microsoft decide to do.